# MySQL SUM and GROUP BY from AS column

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

table1 structure and sample data

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
| ID | DESCRIPTION | QUANTITY | EACH | PRICE |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
| 1  | Product 1   |     1    |  12  | 1*12  |
| 2  | Product 2   |     2    |   3  | 2* 3  |
| 3  | Prodcut 3   |   NULL   |   3  |       |
| 4  | Product 1   |     2    |  10  | 2*10  |
| 5  | Product 3   |   NULL   |   7  |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  COALESCE(QUANTITY, 1) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION
```

How could I make **SUM** for the *PRICE* column and **GROUP BY** the *DESCRIPTION* column? I don't want to use UPDATE because I can't change the values in the table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well why can't you add `SUM(COALESCE(QUANTITY, 1) * EACH) AS PRICETOTAL` in your select list.

Comment: And perhaps tweak the group by clause a little bit as well to make it compliant with the sql standards...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DESCRIPTION,
    SUM(COALESCE(QUANTITY,1)*each) as 'Price'
FROM table1
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION


returns 
DESCRIPTION Price
Product 1   32
Product 2   6
Product 3   10
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!